# Change the duration of "Put hard disks to sleep when possible"

Tags: hard-drive, sleep-wake, external-disk

In general, the "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" function is very helpful to extend the hard drive's lifespan, but in large, it becomes a problem.

Due to how hard drives work, if you put a hard drive near you on the desk in a quiet room, you would be able to hear that sound.

The problem is that I've discovered that the OS puts the hard drive to sleep far too frequently; for example, when I close the finder or any app that relies on reading a file from the hard drive, it only waits about 2 seconds before shutting down the hard drive.

This has caused a lot of lag whenever an application tries to read files on a hard drive and has to wait for a prolonged 2-3 seconds for the disk to spin up, and then as soon as the reading/writing ended, the hard drive shut off immediately.

Is there anyway to change the waiting time for the hard drive to rest? Let's say after 600 seconds of idle, the hard drive may go into sleep.

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal, look at the options for the command line tool `pmset`.

From the manual (`man pmset`) the key is `disksleep` with a number of minutes and there are other settings available.

For your example, the command would be `sudo pmset disksleep 10`.